# windows 10 PowerShell not working [error 2147942405 (0x80070005) when launching `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe']

Tags: powershell

[error 2147942405 (0x80070005) when launching `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe']

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4BAq.png)

windows cannot access the specified device path or file you may not have appropriate permissions

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: We are here to assist with PS code issues. This is not a code issue. This is an environmental issue. Was it working before If so, then you or something messed with your system? If you are on Windows and had System Restore points activated, then roll back to a date when things were working.

Comment: The error indeed suggests a lack of permissions, which is certainly unexpected: see https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_WIN32/0x80070005